# Umbraco 7 rich text editor cant add link

Tags: umbraco

The add/edit link in the rich text editor in umbraco isn't working for me. I use it as below:

[image]

But when i view the source the link has no href

```html
<a>angular.io</a>
```

- and it doenst work on the front end either? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mind showing your view code?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to add a link in a tinyMCE editor.

[image]

Comment: You have not read the question, I can add a link but the functionality is broken

Answer (score 0):

Which Umbraco version are you using?

I had the same issue few days ago. 
After upgrading Umbraco to the latest version (7.12.3) it seems to work again.

Try to upgrade your Umbraco installation if you haven't.